# Best practice converting RDL to RDLC

Tags: c#, dataset, reporting-services

I'm looking to move from RDL to RDLC files, for my reports.

The reasons are:

- Perfomance (Reports are RDLC files perform better)
- Firewall issues (i need port 80 to be open to connect to the SQL Server reportserver)

My ideal situation would be the following:
Create the report as a RDL file, so it can easily be edited.
Deploy it as a RDLC to the webapp.

Have a module extract the querys and parameters stored in the RDLC and created and pass the datasets to the reportviewer.

In this scenario its easy to maintain.
Any idea if such is available, or directions to create it?

Answer (score 10):

Microsoft provides documents about Converting RDL to RDLC files

You can find the document in MSDN: [Converting RDL and RDLC Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(v=vs.140).aspx)
If you need the docs for another Visual-Studio Version, there's a version selector on the page.

Comment: Thanx, im aware of this article. Im looking for a automatic way of converting, without the need to create the datasets myself, but extractet from the defnition in the rdlc file

Comment: Since RDLC is xml-ish you could perhaps  use a t4-template for generating the datasets?

Comment: The link now refers to Visual Studio 2005 Retired documentations.  Try this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I replaced it with the 14.0 Version link

Comment: That article only discusses conversion of RDLC to RDL files. The original poster (and me!) wants to go the other way, ie RDL to RDLC?

Answer (score 6):

It seems apparent that there is no viable solution for your scenario.

I suggest you reconsider your original reasons:

- Performance - I'm not aware of any significant performance difference.  In fact an SSRS server will usually out-perform an RDLC solution overall due to scalability and caching features
- Firewall issues - SSRS server is not restricted to port 80, ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159261.aspx